# Joining multiple tables in Django 1.9

Tags: django

I am still learning Django. Anyone who is knowledgeable in Django 1.8 or greater who can help me about this. I have problem in joining these 5 tables, I want to execute a query which is equivalent to this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
from modelname1 a 
join modelname2 b on a.id = b.id 
join modelname3 c on c.id = b.id 
join modelname4 d on d.id = c.id 
join modelname5 on e.id = d.id;
```

I have these models:

```
class modelname1(models.Model):
    modelname1_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class modelname2(models.Model):
    modelname2_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    c = models.ForeignKey(modelname1)

class modelname3(models.Model):
    modelname3_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    c = models.ForeignKey(modelname2)

class modelname4(models.Model):
    modelname4_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    c = models.ForeignKey(modelname3)

class modelname5(models.Model):
    modelname5_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    c = models.ForeignKey(modelname4)
```

I don't know how to translate the query I want above in Django, 
I can make the query which resulted to the same answer but I need to divide it into multiple queries before getting the same answer.
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I would recommend you to change your mindset. You probably do not need to "translate" to your query, just use ORM to get the value of any field you like.

Comment: Which fields do you finally seek in your output?

Comment: @AKS - I want to join all the table in one query and have a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django you can simply query like this:

```
>>>from app.models import modelname1
>>> q = modelname1.objects.get(id = 1)
>>> m2 = q.modelname2 # In django 1.8 or later
>>> m3 = m2.modelname3
>>> m4 = m3.modelname4
... And so on!
```

But I don't offer this way because of lots of database hitting. If you want optimize your database access can read this article:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/optimization/

Comment: that is the way i got the same answer on my problem. I have to hit the database many times to get the answer, all I want is to JOIN the five table by hitting the database once and then have a condition on it. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Your welcome @Abz Rockers, you can change this question status to responsed by hitting the tick, or give a + to my answer if you prefer.